# How an SOA record is used?

Tags: dns-zone, soa-record

I just created a DNS zone in Azure, and an SOA record was created there automatically. Now next task is to map the NameServers with the Domain registrar.

I could not understand, How is SOA record used here.

Does the TLD server fetch the SOA record from NS for verification for ownership?

When does SOA record come into picture for working on DNS system?